# Unable to add a hotmail adress to the win8 mail app

Tags: email, hotmail, windows-8

I have Windows 8 Pro installed on a test machine (latest release, fully updated) and I tried to add a hotmail account to the mail app.
When I tried this the first time, the 'adding process' seemed to work fine, but when it was finished, the mails did not show up in the program. Also I cannot find the account on the account page in the settings.
When I now try to add the account again, it won't let me do it, claiming that this account is already added to the program.

I use the same account for this, that I use to log into the system. The account itself is working fine and I can log in to the hotmail homepage.

 If I try my google mail account, it works fine.

Comment: I am going to guess this is because Hotmail does not offer IMAP support out of the box.  Have you tried switching it over to an Outlook.com to see if that works?

Comment: What do you mean by "switching it over to an Outlook.com"? Normally I don't use hotmail, therefore I am not used to their account system.
Also, do you think that MS was programming a mail client that is unable to use hotmail, but adding an 'add a hotmail account' button to the menu?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem. My Windows Live account is very old, and my logon name is different from the mail address, and I suspect that this is a part of the problem.
I have tried adding my acccount as an outlook account, but still I get a blank page, and i can't see the account under settings. But when i Open my calendar all my appointments are doubled, and in the account settings my outlook account shows up.

I suspect the mail problem has something to do with the fact that I use another mail-address as logon name to my windows live account. Is your logon name and your hotmail address the same or different?

Comment: My account is as old as the system. I just created it for it. The address is the logon